# How to destructure a value in function callback params?

Tags: javascript

How to destructure a value in function callback params?

Here I want to assign the `{ center: [lat, lng] } = {center, [0,0]}`. Such that a destructuring error won't be thrown.

or we can do something like this : `{ center: [lat, lng] } || {center: [0,0]}`

```
        tap(({ center: [lat, lng] } = {center: [0,0]}) =>
           console.log(lat, lng)
        )
```

Is that possible?

Comment: It's more than just the `,` typo.

Comment: I'd use a combination of destructuring default values and parameter default values: https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/zap2dL10/

Comment: I missed that typo. I updated the question. In my real app there was no type. I think I made a mistake while entering here> I have removed the ```,``` typo/